# Trying to create my .cspkg Azure package file, but getting an error "Need to specify the physical directory for the virtual path..."

Tags: azure, package, webrole

When I try to package my Azure web app (to create the .cspkg and .cscfg files), I get the following error in my ServiceDefinition.csdef file:

> Need to specify the physical directory for the virtual path
>   'AzurePOCWebRole/' of role AzurePOCWebRole

Here's my .csdef file:

[image]

I'm assuming the error is referring to my `<Site name="AzurePOCWebRole">` piece.  I try adding `physicalDirectory` to `<Site name="AzurePOCWebRole" physicalDirectory="../AzurePOCWebRole">`:

[image]

And try to create the package again, but I get the same error and it reverts that change I just made back to `<Site name="AzurePOCWebRole">`:

[image]

**QUESTION**: What can I do to resolve this error and create my package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was editing the "automatically generated" version of ServiceDefinition.csdef, which wasn't apparent because it didn't indicate it wasn't the actual file, so whenever I rebuilt, it reverted this file back to the original ServiceDefinition.csdef's file, which I WASN'T editing.