# error CloudServices077: Need to specify the physical directory for the virtual path 'Web/' of role

Tags: azure, msbuild, azure-sdk-.net

I have a large solution file with many projects. Included are three Azure web role projects. We are using MSBuild to build the solution like this:

```
<MSBuild
  Projects="$(ProductRoot)\Product.sln"
  Properties="Configuration=$(BuildConfiguration);OutputPath=$(OutputPath)\Product;OutDir=$(OutputPath)\Product\;TargetProfile=$(TargetProfile);CloudExtensionsDir=$(CloudExtensionsDir);ServiceHostingSDKInstallDir=$(ServiceHostingSDKInstallDir);AzureClientLibInstallDir=$(AzureClientLibInstallDir);GenerateProjectSpecificOutputFolder=true"
  Targets="Build;Publish"/>
```

However, for our Azure projects, this is failing with:
error CloudServices077: Need to specify the physical directory for the virtual path 'Web/' of role WebService.

The solution builds fine in Visual Studio 2015.

I don't understand why it would fail with this error. We only have one Site in each of our cloud projects and a physicalDirectory should not be required. Here is from the CSDEF:

```
<Sites>
  <Site name="Web">
    <Bindings>
      <Binding name="Endpoint1" endpointName="WebService" />
    </Bindings>
  </Site>
</Sites>
```

I don't even know what I would want to put for the physicalDirectory.

To add more confusion to this, I have found that if I only MSBuild the solution with the Build target, but then MSBuild each of my cloud project (CCPROJ) files with a Publish target, then it works fine! But I need to publish the entire solution without managing individual projects in MSBuild.

The only other reference to this problem I've been able to find on the internet comes from this blog entry:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tomholl/2011/10/19/updates-to-windows-azure-msbuild-post-for-sdk-1-5/
And it implicitly suggests I can work around this by specifying PackageForComputeEmulator. First, I don't know if I am reading that correctly, and secondly even if I am, I would want to understand how the built CSPKG file differs with and without PackageForComputeEmulator being specified. I.e. is it still possible and safe to deploy it to a production environment with PackageForComputeEmulator set?

If anybody has any idea why I am getting this error and know how I can resolve it, I would appreciate it!

Below is spew from MSBuild diagnostic build which gives the error:

```
Target "Build" skipped. Previously built successfully.
Target "CorePublish" in file "C:\tfs\azure\2.8\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.targets" from project "C:\tfs\Product\WebService.Cloud\WebService.Cloud.ccproj" (target "Publish" depends on it):
Task "Message"
  CorePublish: PackageWebRole = True
Done executing task "Message".
Task "Message"
  Publishing starting...
Done executing task "Message".
Task "Message"
  RolePlugins       is 
Done executing task "Message".
Task "Message"
  Importedmodules is 
Done executing task "Message".
Task "Message"
  Publishing to 'c:\Build\Productapp.publish\'
Done executing task "Message".
Task "MakeDir"
  Creating directory "c:\Build\Productapp.publish\".
Done executing task "MakeDir".
Task "Message"
  TargetServiceDefinition is c:\Build\Product\WebService.Cloud\ServiceDefinition.csdef
Done executing task "Message".
Task "Message"
  TargetServiceConfiguration is c:\Build\Product\WebService.Cloud\ServiceConfiguration.cscfg
Done executing task "Message".
Task "Message"
  Roles is 
Done executing task "Message".
Using "CSPack" task from assembly "C:\tfs\azure\v2.8\bin\Microsoft.ServiceHosting.Tools.MSBuildTasks.dll".
Task "CSPack"
  Searching for imported module RemoteAccess at C:\tfs\azure\v2.8\bin\plugins\RemoteAccess\RemoteAccess.csplugin...
  Searching for imported module RemoteForwarder at C:\tfs\azure\v2.8\bin\plugins\RemoteForwarder\RemoteForwarder.csplugin...
C:\tfs\azure\2.8\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.targets(3003,5): warning : CloudServices68 : No TargetFrameworkVersion specified for role WebService. Using .NET framework v4.0 for packaging. [C:\tfs\Product\WebService.Cloud\WebService.Cloud.ccproj]
c:\Build\Product\WebService.Cloud\ServiceDefinition.csdef : error CloudServices077: Need to specify the physical directory for the virtual path 'Web/' of role WebService. [C:\tfs\Product\WebService.Cloud\WebService.Cloud.ccproj]
Done executing task "CSPack" -- FAILED.
Done building target "CorePublish" in project "WebService.Cloud.ccproj" -- FAILED.
Done Building Project "C:\tfs\Product\WebService.Cloud\WebService.Cloud.ccproj" (Publish target(s)) -- FAILED.
```

Answer (score 0):

Although this post is old, just in case there is someone like me who is also looking for solution for the error "Need to specify the physical directory for the virtual path" when trying to add multiple websites in Microsoft Azure Cloud Service, I'd like to share how I solve it.

There is only one file that we need to change, i.e. **ServiceDefinition.csdef**.

Before getting started, please make sure that you are not editing on the automatically generated version of the ServiceDefinition.csdef. This mistake is shared at another post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17554795/1177328.

I have the following code in my ServiceDefinition.csdef under .

```
<Sites>
  <Site name="Web">
    <VirtualApplication name="admin" physicalDirectory="..\..\..\Admin" />
    <Bindings>
      <Binding name="Endpoint" endpointName="EndpointHttp" />
    </Bindings>
  </Site>
</Sites>
```

By doing this, I will have the website in **Admin** folder to be accessible differently. For example, if my primary website is http://www.mywebsite.com, then the **Admin** virtual web application above will be accessed at http://www.mywebsite.com/admin.

Read more about this at https://cuteprogramming.wordpress.com/2015/08/25/azure-cloud-service-say-hi-to-paas.

---

So now if I'd like to add one more new website to the same Web Role, I will just need to add one more `<Site>` element as follows.

```
<Site name="2ndWeb" physicalDirectory="..\..\..\2ndWeb">
    <Bindings>
      <Binding name="NewWebsiteEndpoint1" 
          endpointName="Endpoint1" hostHeader="www.mywebsite.com" />
    </Bindings>
</Site>
```

Common mistake here is to forget adding physicalDirectory for the `<Site>` element, which will then throw the error above **"Need to specify the physical directory for the virtual path"**.

You can read more about adding three or more websites in the same Web Role at http://www.wadewegner.com/2011/02/running-multiple-websites-in-a-windows-azure-web-role.

So to answer Agendum's question above, perhaps you can try add the attribute physicalDirectory to your `<Site>`. Hope it helps!